# add two sum with join and group by in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name,SUM(t3.points), SUM(t2.points)
FROM app_users t1
LEFT JOIN loyalty_points_redeem t3 ON t3.app_user_id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN loyalty_points_gain t2 ON t2.app_user_id = t1.id    
GROUP BY t1.id
```

i want to calculate the sum of a particilar i from  table first sum is ok but another is incorrect i am new in sql how to solve that if any idea please help

Comment: what do you mean by incorrect, please add an example

Comment: calculation of SUM(t3.points) is wrong

Comment: provide sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: id
name
SUM(t3.points)
SUM(t2.points)
1
vinayak
1000
94
2
shashank
NULL
NULL
3
Kaustubh
NULL
NULL
4
Markanday
NULL
NULL
13
vinayak
NULL
NULL
14
chirag jain
NULL
NULL
15
testing testing
NULL
NULL
16
manoj shinde
NULL
NULL
17
vinayak
NULL
12550

Comment: Add some sample data of table and what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can try below  by adding t1.name in group by clause

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name,SUM(t3.points), SUM(t2.points)
FROM app_users t1
LEFT JOIN loyalty_points_redeem t3 ON t3.app_user_id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN loyalty_points_gain t2 ON t2.app_user_id = t1.id    
GROUP BY t1.id,t1.name
```

Comment: SUM(t3.points) coloumn output calculation is wrong in both case my and you

Comment: can you please add some sample data and your expected output in question - it'll be more easy to understand @manishkumaryadav

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt see a problem othertah the GROUP BY

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name,SUM(t3.points), SUM(t2.points)
FROM app_users t1
LEFT JOIN loyalty_points_redeem t3 ON t3.app_user_id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN loyalty_points_gain t2 ON t2.app_user_id = t1.id    
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name
```

Comment: Update the description with some sample data of table and what exactly  you want